# ValueError at /state/ Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, forms

I am getting this error and i have tried typecasting to change it to an integer but it still gives an error.

I don't know what's wrong with the code and i am stuck here from past 30 minutes. Can someone help?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', cview.Insertrecord),
    path('country/', lview.Insertrecord),
    path('state/', lview.Insertrecord_state),
]
```

---

models.py

```
class customer_state(models.Model):
    parent_id=models.ForeignKey(customer_location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='nil')
    added_by=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=1)
    updated_by=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=1)
    created_on=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    updated_on=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table="customer_state"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created_on = get_current_datetime_str()
        self.updated_on = get_current_datetime_str()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

views.py

```
def Insertrecord_state(request):
    # Define the parent_id variable
    parent_id = None
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('parent_id')...... and request.POST.get('updated_on'):
           
            parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
            
            parent_location = customer_location.objects.get(id=parent_id)
            
            saverecord=customer_state()
            saverecord.parent_id=parent_location
            saverecord.name=request.POST.get('name')
            
            saverecord.save()
            messages.success(request,"Record Saved Successfully..!")
            return render(request, 'state.html', {'parent_id': parent_id})
    else:
        # Return the form with the parent_id variable
        return render(request,'state.html', {'parent_id': parent_id})
```

---

state.html

```
 <div class="container-sm">
      <form method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row mb-3" style="display:none">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Parent ID</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" value="{{ parent_id }}" name="parent_id" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
         .
         .
</form>
```

Error Message:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the full error?

Comment: Exception Type: ValueError at /state/
Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message, the full traceback, and any code of yours that is mentioned in the traceback.

Comment: see i have uploaded the screenshot of error message

Comment: plz add full code of HTML

Comment: i am not able to add more of html code as it the limit gets increased